# vim: command map to two commands gives E488

Tags: vim, vimrc

I'd like a `Build` command that starts a build independent of what build system is used.

```
command! -nargs=* Build :Makeshift<Bar>MakeshiftBuild <args>
```

gives me

```
E488: Trailing characters
```

Either one can be mapped and works, but the two of them produce the error.
I tried `-bar` on my map. I cannot change Makeshift to use it.

The following works:

```
function! s:BuildFun(what2build)
    execute 'Makeshift'
    execute 'MakeshiftBuild '.a:what2build
endfunction
command! -nargs=* Build :call s:BuildFun(<q-args>)
```

Can someone clarify, why the one-liner does not work or how to make it work.
Just to gain insight.

Comment: This works fine for me.

Comment: `johnsyweb/vim-makeshift` or do you use a different one?

Comment: No, I just tested with made-up `Makeshift` and `MakeshiftBuild` commands. Now I see the problem. For custom commands to be chainable via `|`, they need the `-bar` attribute. [`Makeshift`](https://github.com/johnsyweb/vim-makeshift/blob/master/plugin/makeshift.vim#L115) is not defined with `-bar`.

Comment: Thanks. This is solved then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is in the comment: `Makeshift` was defined without a `-bar` parameter. From vim `help command`:

```
-bar        The command can be followed by a "|" and another command.
            A "|" inside the command argument is not allowed then.
            Also checks for a " to start a comment.
```

In such cases there is no need to fork the plugin repo, because one can use the workaround with the function, as shown above. This is then the general solution, as pointed out in https://stackoverflow.com/a/3266791/1803897.

Comment: If you still have a question/problem, given that no one else has answered yet, consider editing your question to add the workaround you have so far, leaving Answerers to address the remainder.  Thanks!